# How to get MySQL result set with lowest picture number?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get a result set out of a MySQL database where there are multiple pictures referenced to each item. The pictures have a picture_no field where the lowest number is the one I want to return with the result.

Currently I am using this query:

```
SELECT 
    ca.*,
    ca.ID AS ad_id,
    ca.cat_id,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ca.date_edited) AS date,
    cp.*,
    ar.area_name
FROM  
    $DB.$T4 ca
        LEFT JOIN $T6 AS cp ON ca.ID = cp.classified_id AND cp.picture_no = 0 
        LEFT JOIN $T60  zip ON ca.zip_id = zip.zip_id
        LEFT JOIN $T3    ar  ON zip.area_id = ar.ID
WHERE
    ca.extern = 0
    AND ca.confirmed = 1
    AND ca.advertiser_id = ".$user['uid']."
ORDER BY 
    date_created        
LIMIT 10
```

As you can see, I am currently using `AND cp.picture_no = 0` since I could not figure out how to get the picture with the lowest number.

How could this be done? The function min() did not help me to solve the problem.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Do you need every column from the `cp` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
SELECT 
    ca.*,
    ca.ID AS ad_id,
    ca.cat_id,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ca.date_edited) AS date,
    cp.*,
    ar.area_name
FROM  
    $DB.$T4 ca
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT tmp.*
                   FROM $T6 tmp
                   INNER JOIN (SELECT classified_id, MIN(picture_no) min_picture_no
                               FROM $T6
                               GROUP BY classified_id) tmp1
                    ON tmp.classified_id = tmp1.classified_id 
                            and tmp.picture_no = tmp1.min_picture_no
                    ) AS cp 
        ON ca.ID = cp.classified_id
        LEFT JOIN $T60  zip ON ca.zip_id = zip.zip_id
        LEFT JOIN $T3   ar  ON zip.area_id = ar.ID
WHERE
    ca.extern = 0
    AND ca.confirmed = 1
    AND ca.advertiser_id = ".$user['uid']."
ORDER BY 
    date_created        
LIMIT 10
```

Editted: remove `AND cp.picture_no = 0` as it's only temp solution of asker. Thanks `Paul Spiegel` for suggestion.

Comment: `AND cp.picture_no = 0 ` was a workaround. You should remove it.

Comment: This looks like it could work. I do get "#1060 - Duplicate column name 'classified_id' " though. Also I am wondering if this solution will be fast enough. The script runs as a cron_job within a loop for every user out of aprox 50K users.

Comment: Pefect! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the join into something like this:

```
 LEFT JOIN (select * from $T6 AS cp where ca.ID = cp.classified_id order by picture_no asc limit 1) on ca.ID = cp.classified_id
```

Comment: "Subqueries in the FROM clause cannot be correlated subqueries, unless used within the ON clause of a JOIN operation." [Subqueries in the FROM Clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/from-clause-subqueries.html).

Comment: @PhamX.Bach - If used correctly in the ON clause, MySQL should cache the result for each `ca.ID`.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the best variant, but you can replace :

```
LEFT JOIN $T6 AS cp ON ca.ID = cp.classified_id AND cp.picture_no = 0
```

with :

```
LEFT JOIN $T6 AS cp ON ca.ID = cp.classified_id  
LEFT JOIN $T6 AS cp_temp 
ON cp_temp.ID = cp.classified_id 
 AND cp_temp.picture_no < cp.picture_no
```

and add `AND cp_temp.id IS NULL` to where clause at the end of query.

So final query could be something like:

```
SELECT 
  ca.*,
  ca.ID AS ad_id,
  ca.cat_id,
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ca.date_edited) AS date,
  cp.*,
  ar.area_name
FROM  $DB.$T4 ca
LEFT JOIN $T6 AS cp 
ON ca.ID = cp.classified_id  
LEFT JOIN $T6 AS cp_temp 
ON cp_temp.ID = cp.classified_id 
  AND cp_temp.picture_no < cp.picture_no 
LEFT JOIN $T60  zip 
ON ca.zip_id = zip.zip_id
LEFT JOIN $T3   ar  
ON zip.area_id = ar.ID
WHERE ca.extern = 0
  AND ca.confirmed = 1
  AND ca.advertiser_id = ".$user['uid']."
  AND cp_temp.id IS NULL
ORDER BY date_created        
LIMIT 10
```